# Time/date implementation on a MCU

Tags: c, date, time, microcontroller, elapsedtime

I am working on a MCU and my aim is to implement time/date on the MCU.

I use a timer that ticks per seconds and store it on `uint32_t count` that has enough size to store 136 years. I want to have 2000 as a reference and max should be 2099.

here is my data struct:

```
typedef struct
{
uint8_t sec;        // Seconds. [0-60] (1 leap second) 
uint8_t min;        // Minutes. [0-59] 
uint8_t hour;       // Hours.   [0-23] 
uint8_t day;        // Day.     [1-31] 
uint8_t month;      // Month.   [0-11] 
uint8_t year;       // Year - from 2000.  [00-99] 
} osal_time_t;
```

What is a best way to convert the seconds(`uint32_t count`) to min/hr/day/month/year correctly and by using the lowest resources?

Time, hour, and year seems simple but day gets tricky with 28-29-30-31 days and feb is 29 each 4 years.

I see linux source code implementations but I think it is designed an OS, not best of a humble MCU.

Can anyone hint what kind of algorithm should I use in a MCU so that it requires min. resources?

As an example, what algorithm is used to calculate this http://www.mathcats.com/explore/elapsedtime.html

If you have any code snippet, I would appreciate if you could share it.

Comment: I'd just like to point out that you can get RTC (real-time clock) modules for pennies on ebay that implement very simple communication interfaces and usually have a slot for a battery that will keep them going for years even if the MCU is off.

Comment: Can you not just use the time C library?

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/time_h.htm

Comment: Smells like X-Y problem. Why do you need to convert seconds to time+date+year and who cares about it?

Comment: @MatthewGoulart: 1) ebay is a bad source for a professional product (we don't know!) 2) One often has not the space to use some extra hardware or the weight is a problem 3) Even some "pennies" are an issue for large volume products 4) It is a good practice to implement this in software.

Comment: I didn't want to explain all the implementation and why since the question will be too long and too many relevant information. I am aware of RTC but I can't use in my application. I am using the time to schedule events for a specific time of a day. E.g., a user can schedule what the system should do at a Feb 27 at 4:30:27. I plan to update the schedule per month due to flash limitation. One preference to convert Feb 27... to seconds from 2000, the question will be the same, what algorithm to calculate the elapsed time

Comment: Sorry, this is too broad. SHow your code and where you have a **specific** problem. Recommendation: You should use the linear counter throughout your code. Only for input/output iff(!) a human-readable format is required, you should convert (i.e. display/keyboard). For many embedded systems this means you can convert the data on a PC (just output/input the linear time from/to your device).

Comment: @olaf thats why I said it in the comments and not as an answer. I was just pointing it out in case it could save sven some time. No need to pick apart a suggestion in the comments. And in fact it is NOT good practice to implement time-critical applications on MCU counters as they are not as precise as some RTC modules and can be seconds off after only a week or two.

Comment: @MatthewGoulart: It is bad as any of them. Just like a comment for a C question recommending to use a different programming language just because that has the feature built-in.

Comment: Why not have the timer that ticks every second update the struct immediately? Every second add one to `osal_time_t.sec` until it reaches 60 then add one to minutes and reset seconds, etc...

Comment: @user1320881: This results in quite some overhead and less predictable run-time of the interrupt handler. If the conversion is only required on rare occasions, it is nonsense. Also a linear counter allows e.g. easy and fast comparison/difference, etc.

Comment: @Olaf. Depending on how often the time is needed, calculating it from the year 2000 + seconds seems more expensive to me then just adding some counters every second.

Comment: I use counter++ at each clock which requires only one clock cycle, conversion requires more clock cycles. program needs less often the conversion. Olaf's suggestions are good and it is what I do. I have just implemented the time. I want to test the MCU for couple days and I want to send time query request to MCU to see if the time is accurate after couple days later. Since my MCU is not powered by a battery etc, I want to do the conversion in the MCU, I think debugging will benefit it.

Comment: I appreciate the comments, but I'd be grateful for an answer for the asked question than questioning the design purpose and preferences.

Comment: If you look at the page you linked as example, you'll find some javascript that you can follow. Your question is "What is the best method?" which is liable to attract opinionated answers, as can be seen. I recommend you do some more research, which will also correct your misconception that a leap year is every 4 years (2100 will not be a leap year).

Comment: Are you sure you need to handle leap seconds? They are hairy to deal with, and if you're using SW clock it's not going to be too precise anyway.

Comment: @user1320881: Instead of just incrementing a single counter (not sure where you get the `+ 2000` from), you have to increment and compare **at least** one counter. It becomes much worse for days, as the max. depends on the month, then leap-years, etc. Yes, it **is** faster.

Comment: @WeatherVane: That is too far in the future. No one will use that program until then - Y2K1 ;-)

Comment: @Olaf I expect you made the same remark in 1985 about Y2K? OP wants 136 year range. He might want a wake-up call from deep sleep on approach to Alpha Centauri.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Sure. I still use 2 digits BCD. That is enough. Just a matter of interpretation. We already know which century it is ... And I use still Z80 because most modern CPUs don't support BCD arithmetic.

Comment: @Olaf perhaps OP should edit his question - *"max should be 2999."*

Comment: @WeatherVane: I still can't figure out how `2000 + 136 == 2999`.

Comment: @Olaf neither could I, unless he holds a variable for the century and resets the counter. Perhap he meant `2099` after all.

Comment: @WeatherVane: So much about "2 digits are enough".

Comment: thank you, I changed to 2099. but I store it with 2 digit as Olaf says. I noted it on the comment part of the code " [00-99] "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to just do the math, there is no other way around it.  You are converting from base 2 to base 10 (base 60 represented in base 10).

Likewise for month day stuff, you have to grind through that as well, with a table of some sort for days per month and deal with leap year.

The alternative to doing the math is changing how you count, using more memory but less calculation.  Basically a BCD approach.  When the ones of seconds rolls from 9 to 10 then increment tens of seconds and set ones of seconds to a 0.  Repeat all the way up to the date.  Or meet half way and seconds over 59 rolls to zero and increments minutes...then do the base 10 stuff to separate the tens from ones of seconds minutes hours.  you could use a table for that if you dont have a divide.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a programming problem, because you can't do this reliably with just a microcontroller. An internal RC oscillator will be way too inaccurate, and even if you use a high accuracy external crystal oscillator, it will drift over time and may vary with temperature.

The only correct solution is to add a real-time clock circuit to the hardware, preferably together with a back-up battery. How to communicate with the real-time clock circuit is hardware-specific.

It is better to ask such questions which are on the borderland to hardware on https://electronics.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: I agree that it will drift over the time, that's why I update it each time from an edge router, but I wrote in the comments that I don't write system details and preferences, because question is a C question, not a system design. I have 24 MHz 10ppm crystal, OSAL timer is used in embedded systems, such as many ZigBee devices. It is not the best, but it is still good enough for my application. I considered it to post it on electronics.stackexchange, but it is not an electronics design question, I am asking a best C method to convert the date. I think dwelch has the most accurate answer

Comment: just a correction in the answer that one can implement a precise clock signal on a MCU by using temperature compensated crystal (referring the temp. drift).

Comment: I completely agree with this, but an RTC drifts as well, not as much but can/will drift too.  All depends on the quality (read: expense) of the clock circuit and how you maintain it (power, temperature, etc).

Comment: How is a question about algorithm not a programming question, and how can an algorithm not be reliably done with a microcontroller? (Having an accurate clock source to count time is an entirely different topic but the OP did not ask about that.)

Comment: @tonypdmtr Because the RTC will be external and so how to get the time will depend entirely on what hardware the RTC got. Maybe it is just some SPI interface and then you read the whole time from it in one go. Then there is no need for any algorithm.